# Manually building R packages in Linux

Tags: r, linux, package

I am working on Debian Stable Linux and had installed R version 3.3 from its repository. I had also installed many packages using command `install.packages('pkgname')` from R command line.

I have now also installed R version 3.5 downloaded from its website using following commands to a folder named `~/myR`:

```
./configure --prefix=~/myR --enable-R-shlib 
make 
make install
```

It has installed all right and I can now run version 3.5 by giving command `R` in folder `~/myR/bin`

Is it possible now to shift packages installed using `install.packages` command from within older R to this manually installed R? These packages are currently installed in `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3`. If I transfer them to folder `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5`, will it work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest to reinstall all the packages.

Comment: You could try the R command `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)` to that end

Comment: I simply renamed folder `3.3` in  `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/` to `3.5` and ran `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)` from new R installation. It worked!